# select only specific file type using intent.getContent method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to select some files from the device on specific event using following code.

For Audio i used:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select ,Music"),AUDIO_REQUEST);
```

But Problem is when user tries to select from es file explorer it also allows other file types to be selected. How can I prevent other file types to be selected and allow only audio types. The screendshot is here. [image: Screenshot]

**Edit**

I also wanted to select document file type such as doc ppt xl etc.
for that I have used

```
String[] mimeTypes = {"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", // .doc & .docx
                            "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", // .ppt & .pptx
                            "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", // .xls & .xlsx
                            "text/plain",
                            "application/pdf"};

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
} else {
       String mimeTypesStr = "";
        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
                 mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }
       intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
}
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select Document"),DOCUMENT_REQUEST);
```

But, Same thing with happened to this also.
Can Anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978581/how-to-make-intent-settype-for-pdf-xlsx-and-txt-file-android) may help.

Comment: And use file Providor for passing the audio file URI else version >= Nougat wont be supported..

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428647/android-select-mp3-file may help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed suggested..

Comment: you are setting `intent.setType("*/*");` which is letting to select any file

Comment: but, for audio I have set Intent.setType(audio/*). then, why I am getting result like this.@RahulKhurana

Comment: i see, you found your solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
```

or

```
intent.setType("audio/mp3");
```

or try like this

```
Intent intent = null;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    }else {
         intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    }

    // The MIME data type filter
    intent.setType("audio/*")
```